# Database has the date format Y.M.D H: i: s but my BETWEEN has the date format Y.M: D

Tags: mysql

I have the following problem: I would like to use this MYSQL Querie:

```
SELECT * FROM sfe_igv_gutscheine WHERE art LIKE '%privat%' AND farbe LIKE '%Rot%' AND wert LIKE '%10€%' AND DATE_FORMAT(ausgegeben_am, '%Y/%m/%d') between 2020-08-01 AND 2020-08-31
```

Let me print out all the dates. Unfortunately I don't get a result back. The data record is stored in the database with the date format Y.M: D H: i: s. However, my BETWEEN in my SQL Querie has the date format Y.M.D. Is there a simple solution? At the end, all data records should be output between this period.

Kind regards and thank you

Comment: 2020-08-01 is 2020 minus 08 minus 01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using quotes around the dates. Otherwise it will calculate 2020 minus 8 minus 1. ;)

`between '2020-08-01' and '2020-08-31'`